# Enable Adblocker Extension In Chrome Using RSelenium

Tags: r, google-chrome, selenium, rselenium

I am scraping data in R from this page, http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=earningsdate_nextdays5 which displays popup ads. Those ads interfere with script so I'd like to enable the adblocker extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom

I'm working with code in the RSelenium package documentation here, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/RSelenium.pdf

I found the profile directory by opening a chrome browser and navigating to: chrome://version/. This is my usual profile which has the adblocker extension enabled.

However, when I open chrome, no adblocker is there. I looked at this page, http://scottcsims.com/wordpress/?p=450 and he suggests using the add_extension method which doesn't appear to be implemented in RSelenium.

Any idea on how I can get the adblocker enabled in the browser that R opens?

My code so far. Please note, this was done on a mac and of course your username will be different than mine, so be sure to change the first argument in getChromeProfile to what you find in Profile Path on this page, chrome://version/

```
require(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer()
cprof <- getChromeProfile("/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/", "Profile 1")
remDr <<- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", extraCapabilities = cprof)
remDr$open()
appURL <- "http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=earningsdate_nextdays5"
remDr$navigate(appURL)
```

Comment: Should it be `cprof <- getChromeProfile("/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome", "Profile 1")` . This would open profile `Profile 1` from the MAC default chrome profile directory.

Comment: Hi JD, that also opens chrome but the extensions do not load with it.

Comment: To clarify if your profile is `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1` you would use `getChromeProfile("/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome", "Profile 1")` . If your profile was in `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default` you would use `getChromeProfile("/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome", "Default")`.

Comment: I have updated my sample code to relfect cprof <- getChromeProfile("/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/", "Profile 1"). However, only some of the extensions load, the adblocker is not one of them. Profile 1 is the only Profile in the directory which makes sense because I am the only person that uses this computer.

Comment: The Default profile is called `Default` not `Profile 1` (at least on windows). Why not make a seperate profile for Selenium. Your code works on Windows with the correct path to a profile with adblock installed. MAC I couldn't say if it works.

Comment: I created the additional profile and everything worked as planned. The issue I did not anticipate, is that it does not appear that I can keep my usual chrome profile open and open a 2nd one from R. I will try using firefox instead. Thanks JD for the suggestions.

Comment: Very good. Yes you cannot use two profiles at the same time. You should add this as the answer

Comment: Respectfully JD, you should add it as the answer as these are all your suggestions. I will accept it as soon as you do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't ablock extension specifically since I like adguard better, but I always use this:

Download adguard **FROM A BROWSER OTHER THAN CHROME**: https://www.crx4chrome.com/go.php?d=4687&i=158&p=31932&s=1&l=https%3A%2F%2Fclients2.googleusercontent.com%2Fcrx%2Fblobs%2FQwAAAHF3InbmK-wFIemaY3I3BCPa0e33dMYlYToYq-WCs1jSyPlSXnr3dNv-HTinVL8eTmtbBlPjwi-hJEL5_ZnPfXkYphLdiwB7LVwS3slKcj15AMZSmuWuPGYPZfS0woRX9brTIZ8faUYQCg%2Fextension_3_0_13_0.crx

Example download filepath: /Users/admin/Downloads/extension_3_0_13_0.crx

R Code:

```
library(RSelenium) #install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
cprof <- list(chromeOptions = 
                list(extensions = 
                       list(base64enc::base64encode("/Users/admin/Downloads/extension_3_0_13_0.crx"))
                ))


rD <- rsDriver(port = 4444L,extraCapabilities=cprof, browser ="chrome",chromever = "latest"))

#if error port used or need to clear port
#rm(rD)
#rm(remDr)
#gc() #then try again

#set timeout preferences with chrome client
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$setTimeout(type = 'page load', milliseconds = 120000)
remDr$setTimeout(type = 'implicit', milliseconds = 120000)
```

Comment: Do you know how to make it work in together with "profile.managed_default_content_settings.images" = 2L"? That is to disable images