# Enable Adblocker extension In Chrome using latest version of RSelenium

Tags: r, google-chrome, selenium, adblock, rselenium

My question is related to [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40551893/enable-adblocker-extension-in-chrome-using-rselenium), as I'd similarly like to enable AdBlocker when driving Chrome using the latest version of RSelenium (1.7.1). How do you set the Chrome profile in RSelenium now that startServer has been deprecated?

The code I'm using is as follows, but I don't think the last line is correct. At least, the AdBlocker doesn't appear to be working when Chrome is opened using RSelenium. Thoughts?

```
rD <- rsDriver(verbose = F)
remDr <- rD$client
cprof <- getChromeProfile("/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome", "Default")
remDr$extraCapabilities <- cprof
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `extraCapabilities` argument to the `rsDriver` function:

```
cprof <- getChromeProfile("/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome", "Default")
rD <- rsDriver(verbose = F, extraCapabilities = cprof)
remDr <- rD$client
```

UPDATE

You can also add extensions by base 64 encoding the relevant crx file. You can get the chrome crx file from for example http://chrome-extension-downloader.com/ (the id currently for adguard adblocker is: bgnkhhnnamicmpeenaelnjfhikgbkllg) once you have the crx file you will need to base64 encode it. I used https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/base64enc/ for this:

```
library(RSelenium)

cprof <- list(chromeOptions = 
                list(extensions = 
                       list(base64enc::base64encode("C:/Users/john/Downloads/Adguard-AdBlocker_v2.5.11.crx"))
                ))
rD <- rsDriver(verbose = F, extraCapabilities = cprof)
remDr <- rD$client
```

If you wish to encode with `jsonlite`:

```
tmpfile <- "C:/Users/john/Downloads/Adguard-AdBlocker_v2.5.11.crx"
jsonlite::base64_enc(readBin(tmpfile, "raw", file.info(tmpfile)$size))
```

On MAC OSx sierra:

I created a profile by adding a person on chrome "seltestprof". The profile is created in folder which can be found by browsing to chrome://version whilst using the profile. You can see the profile path listed here. Mine was

```
/private/var/folders/c2/d97mz0250bg08rr4g2znxk7m0000gq/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.mS5SA1/Profile 1
```

I ran the following code to use the profile:

```
library(RSelenium)

cprof <- getChromeProfile("/private/var/folders/c2/d97mz0250bg08rr4g2znxk7m0000gq/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.mS5SA1/", "Profile 1")
rD <- rsDriver(verbose = F, extraCapabilities = cprof)
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate("http://ads-blocker.com/testing/")
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

To use a base encoded crx I used the following code:
    library(RSelenium)

```
cprof <- list(
  chromeOptions = 
    list(extensions = 
           list(base64enc::base64encode("/Users/admin/Downloads/Adguard-AdBlocker_v2.5.11.crx"))
    )
)
rD <- rsDriver(verbose = F, extraCapabilities = cprof)
remDr <- rD$client
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Passing `extraCapabilities` to `rsDriver` didn't seem to do the trick, however. Adblocker works when I run Chrome manually, but not when I drive it remotely using RSelenium. Do you know why that would be the case?

Comment: @M.Aitken this is the correct way to use a custom profile. Please check you are correctly identifying the custom profile folder. Also note that two versions of chrome cannot use the same profile so if you have chrome already open it wont work. There is a second method to add extensions which I have added.

Comment: I made sure that the profile folder is identified correctly. I've also made sure to close Chrome prior to opening it with R. Thanks for the alternative solution, but I'm still not getting it to work by encoding the crx file (with either base64enc or jsonlite), as you've suggested. Is this a Mac vs. PC thing, or is something else going on?

Comment: @M.Aitken that works for me on Mac. Is your RSelenium/wdman running the most recent version?

Comment: OK, sorry I think I was mistakenly running RSelenium 1.7.0. Updating to 1.7.1 does indeed solve the problem. The getChromeProfile method still doesn't work for me, but downloading and encoding the crx file does. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @M.Aitken I looked at running a custom profile on mac osx sierra. The profiles are stored in a non obvious location. Browse to chrome://version whilst using the profile to find where. I have added detail in the answer showing how. The custom profile ran correctly for me once the correct PATH was noted and all chrome browsers with that profile were closed.